# JavaScript, increment and add/subtract numbers together on click

Tags: javascript, math

I have a JS issue I'm trying to work out. The functionality should go like this...

On click of value one, display value. 
On click of value two, add current value to value one. (value1 = 9 + value2 = 8 for total of 17).
On click of value three, add values 1 and 2...And so on until all 5 numbers are selected.

However, I want to be able to deselect the numbers (toggle) and reduce the total amount.

Here is my current code.

```js
$(".start-count-1").on("click", function(evt) {
  var $el = $(".increment-number"),
    value = 9;

  evt.preventDefault();

  $({
    percentage: 0
  }).stop(true).animate({
    percentage: value
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    step: function() {
      // percentage with 1 decimal;
      var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;

      $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
    }
  }).promise().done(function() {
    // hard set the value after animation is done to be
    // sure the value is correct
    $el.text(value + "%");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    0% should incraese (add 9 + 8 + 4) and decrease when buttons clicked again.
    <p class="s2-total center increment-number">0%</p>
  </div>


  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <p class="s2-percents-1">9%</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <p class="s2-percents-2">8%</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <p class="s2-percents-3">4%</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 p-0 s2-selections">
      <button class="s2-btn1 start-count-1">9 +</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 p-0 s2-selections">
      <button class="s2-btn2 start-count-2">8 +</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 p-0 s2-selections">
      <button class="s2-btn3 start-count-3">4 +</button>
    </div>

    Subtract number when clicked again...
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I currently only have the value 9 working. 
What should I do to achieve what I'm looking for? Is there already something built that I can reference?

Comment: Hi, can you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , maybe as a jsfiddle, codepen, or just a snippet here inSO ?

Comment: Yes, one moment.

Comment: I updated it with a jsbin since jsfiddle isn't loading...

Comment: You've only addressed the `onclick()` for ".start-count-1". The other buttons are ".start-count-2" and ".start-count-3".

Comment: Perhaps put all buttons in a class ".start-count" and then pass a `data-value` of 1, 2 or 3 to the `onclick` function.

Answer (score 1):

Few points :

1. the selector `.start-count-1` is only for the class `start-count-1` so the other buttons are ignored.
2. you have fixed the value 9 in the function with `value = 9;` hence even if you had the right selector, the increment would always happen to 9.
3. There is no way for the function to know the number 8 or 9 or 4 when you click the buttons for 8+ etc.

What you could try is to use the selector `[class*=start-count-]` to select all with a class containing `start-count-` and then setting a respective value for every button like

`<button class="s2-btn1 start-count-1" value=9>9 +</button>`

And then you could also modify your function to take the value of the clicked button using :

```
value = $(this).val();
```

and finally you could compare if this value is equal to the currently incremented value to either increment or decrement. Something like :

```
if($el.val()==value){
  // here i just set the text to 0%, you could implement a decrement here, or use some other mechanism to if-else the entire logic
  $el.text(0 + "%"); 
return;}
```

A rough implementation of this may be found at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Exception_al/pen/ddmqRj)

This is just to cover the points stated in the beginning of the answer. Any modifications and beautification and logic improvements are for you to implement and of course you could ask in case of doubt again.

--- EDIT ---
To add the toggle feature to add / subtract on clicking the button you could add an additional data attribute to store and check wether to 'add' or not.

A sample codedepen [here](https://codepen.io/Exception_al/pen/BYreQL)

Comment: I'll try this out, I'm working on it now. The only thing I can see that isn't implemented here is adding the numbers together to total them. Setting to 0 on a second click is fine as long as the numbers are added together. Onclick of 9 and 8 should total to 17. I'll check it out and see if I can figure It out.

Comment: The idea is to guide you in the right direction and not do the homework for you ... Good luck

Comment: Yes I know that. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: As a tip, instead of checking the value of `el` you could set another attribute of the `start-count-` elements to `true` or `false` using `$(this).attr(&#39;add&#39;,true);` every time they are clicked and use that value `$(this).attr('add')` to either add or subtract depending on true or false.